# htmlspecialchars doesn't work on string

Tags: php

When I use cURL to get a website and do strlen() on the result I get 72354. But when I pass the result through htmlspecialchars() and then do strlen() I get 0. Any ideas? Here's my code:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/search?q=test');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo strlen($result);
echo '<br>';
echo strlen(htmlspecialchars($result));
```

Comment: *If the input string contains an invalid code unit sequence within the given encoding an empty string will be returned, unless either the ENT_IGNORE or ENT_SUBSTITUTE flags are set.*

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/search?q=test');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo strlen($result);
echo '<br>';
echo strlen(htmlspecialchars($result, ENT_QUOTES));
echo '<br>';
echo htmlspecialchars($result, ENT_COMPAT,'ISO-8859-1', true);

?>
```

Comment: My browser seems to think Google uses UTF8 ?

Comment: @adeno depends on the request. Or better on your browsers settings.